# Override React TypeScript default anchor props

Tags: reactjs, html, typescript

I want to be able to pass `name` to an anchor attribute in React using TypeScript.

```html
<a href="https://www.google.com" name="name">
  link
</a>
```

But `name` is [deprecated](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a) as of HTML5 so react-dom doesn't include it in the type definition (rightly so, but I need it to be rendered for legacy reasons).

So... Is there a way to force the `name` attribute to be rendered without TypeScript complaining?

I created a [minimal repro](https://codesandbox.io/s/zr8jpxq7vm) to illustrate the issue.